# Issue installing HighFreq package in R due to gfortran issue

Tags: r

I cannot for the life of me install HighFreq

```
devtools::install_github(repo="algoquant/HighFreq")
```

Here is my error:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/8.2.0'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib'
ld: library not found for -lgfortran
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [HighFreq.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘HighFreq’
* removing ‘/Users/cassidywaldrep/Library/R/x86_64/4.2/library/HighFreq’
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘/var/folders/j9/2_db0tnd1q36mb4wqp0cn6fr0000gn/T//RtmpYHOuC8/file1341d5cce87e7/HighFreq_0.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Before you comment other tutorials...I have tried EVERYTHING. I have installed Xcode, I have updated all my packages in R, I have restalled R, I have downloaded through this link (https://github.com/fxcoudert/gfortran-for-macOS/releases), I have followed this tutorial (https://blog.cynkra.com/posts/2021-03-16-gfortran-macos/) and installed via Homebrew. But, I still cannot get this package to load. I'm on the verge of frustration.

Will someone please offer up other pieces of advice and walk me through it step by step? I have a MacBook Pro with macOS 13.0 and the Apple M1Pro chip.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Note: I am not an expert Mac M1 user and there are many obscure compiler problems when using R on M1 Mac.

The packages are not really the issue. The issue stems from the way the package builds from `source = TRUE` is true via `install_github`. It expects the `gfortran` library to be in a place where it is no longer supported at. This seems to be a very general and common issue with the M1 and OSX/R community.

This appears to be the issue mentioned in the blog tutorial you linked. A workaround for you is to

1. Ensure that `gfortran` is separately installed as an independent compiler.
2. Fork the repository on GitHub. On your fork, add the following lines to the end of `src/MAKEVARS` file:

```
FC      = usr/local/opt/gcc/bin/gfortran
F77     = /usr/local/opt/gcc/bin/gfortran
FLIBS   = -L/usr/local/opt/gcc/lib
```

**(Note: these lines are assuming these are the installed locations of the binaries for the fortran compiler on your machine. They MAY be different depending on your install method.)**

This tells "your" R package to use these flags when searching for `FC`, `F77`, and `FLIBS` compilers in specific places you have installed them at.

Finally, make sure this fork is available on GitHub and then use `install_github('Cassidy/HighFreq')` (assuming Cassidy is your GH name and HighFreq is the name of the fork). This should allow you do use the source compiler flags that are needed for Fortran.

Also ensure that you are using the newest version of R. Hope this works, but know that the gfortran compiler issue appears to still be quite common.

This is a good place to start. There's still a chance that the compiler flags will somehow conflict with expected versions or have compatibility issues with the existing .cpp flags but I doubt that will happen.